# How to handle a JSON that returns a list of dict-like objects in Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am using an API from collegefootballdata.com to get data on scores and betting lines.  I want to use betting lines to infer expected win % and then compare that to actual results (I feel like my team loses too many games where we are big favorites and want to test that.)  This code retrieves one game for example purposes.

```
parameters = {
"gameId": 401112435,
"year": 2019
}
response = requests.get("https://api.collegefootballdata.com/lines", params=parameters)
```

The JSON output is this:

```
[
{
    "awayConference": "ACC",
    "awayScore": 28,
    "awayTeam": "Virginia Tech",
    "homeConference": "ACC",
    "homeScore": 35,
    "homeTeam": "Boston College",
    "id": 401112435,
    "lines": [
        {
            "formattedSpread": "Virginia Tech -4.5",
            "overUnder": "57.5",
            "provider": "consensus",
            "spread": "4.5"
        },
        {
            "formattedSpread": "Virginia Tech -4.5",
            "overUnder": "57",
            "provider": "Caesars",
            "spread": "4.5"
        },
        {
            "formattedSpread": "Virginia Tech -4.5",
            "overUnder": "58",
            "provider": "numberfire",
            "spread": "4.5"
        },
        {
            "formattedSpread": "Virginia Tech -4.5",
            "overUnder": "56.5",
            "provider": "teamrankings",
            "spread": "4.5"
        }
    ],
    "season": 2019,
    "seasonType": "regular",
    "week": 1
}
]
```

I'm then loading into a pandas dataframe with:

```
def jstring(obj):
    # create a formatted string of the Python JSON object
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    return text

json_str = jstring(response.json())
df = pd.read_json(json_str)
```

This creates a dataframe with a "lines" column that contains the entire lines section of the JSON as a string.  Ultimately, I want to use the "spread" value in the block where "provider" = "consensus".  Everything else is extraneous for my purposes.  I've tried exploding the column with

```
df = df.explode('lines')
```

which gives me 4 rows with something like this for each game (as expected):

```
{'formattedSpread': 'Virginia Tech -4.5', 'overUnder': '57.5', 'provider': 'consensus', 'spread': '4.5'}
```

Here is where I'm stuck.  I want to keep only the rows where 'provider' = 'consensus', and further I need to have 'spread' to use as a separate variable/column in my analysis.  I've tried exploding a 2nd time, df.split, df.replace to change { to [ and explode as a list, all to no avail.  Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for -

EDIT: Handling special case.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

params = {
    "gameId": 401112435,
    "year": 2019,
}

r = requests.get("https://api.collegefootballdata.com/lines", params=params)

df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()) # Create a DataFrame with a lines column that contains JSON
df = df.explode('lines') # Explode the DataFrame so that each line gets its own row
df = df.reset_index(drop=True) # After explosion, the indices are all the same - this resets them so that you can align the DataFrame below cleanly

def fill_na_lines(lines):
    if pd.isna(lines):
        return {k: None for k in ['provider', 'spread', 'formattedSpread', 'overUnder']}
    return lines

df.lines = df.lines.apply(fill_na_lines)

lines_df = pd.DataFrame(df.lines.tolist()) # A separate lines DataFrame created from the lines JSON column
df = pd.concat([df, lines_df], axis=1) # Concatenating the two DataFrames along the vertical axis.

# Now you can filter down to whichever rows you need.
df = df[df.provider == 'consensus']
```

[The documentation on joining DataFrames in different ways is probably useful.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Comment: Follow up question: for some API calls the response JSON has some values in 'lines' that are null.  I get an error on this line:
lines_df = pd.DataFrame(df.lines.tolist())
An example would be using parms = {"team": "Virginia Tech", "year":2020}.
Any ideas how to handle that?

Comment: @HokieSpider I've edited the above response to handle this.